# Selenium Webdriver: How can I avoid the error "ElementNotVisibleException" when trying to select option in dropdown list?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How can I select an item `Option 3` in drop down as below?

```html
    <span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header form-control required" style="padding: 0px;" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-owns="assignee_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="assignee_option_selected">
    <span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on">
    <select id="assignee" class="form-control required" style="padding: 0px; display: none;" name="assignedUserId" data-role="dropdownlist" title="">
        <option value="28941">Option 1</option>
        <option value="28938">Option 2</option>
        <option value="28940">Option 3</option>
        <option value="28942">Option 4</option>
        <option value="28943" selected="selected">Option 5</option>
        <option value="28939">Option 6</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

I tried to select the option 3 on drop-down list, below is my code:

```
public Page selectAsignee(String asignee){
        try{
            WebElement dropdownAsignee = connector.waitForControl(SBConstant.XPATH,dropdownAssignee,3);
            // My xPath is //select[@id='assignee']
            Select select = new Select(dropdownAsignee);
            select.selectByVisibleText("Option 3");
            return this;

        }catch (StaleElementReferenceException s){
            s.toString();
        }
        return this;
    }
```

But it's unable to select option 3 although web driver can detect the select with id ="assignee". 
After run this code, it throws the error like this:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not
>   currently visible and so may not be interacted with

I'm hoping someone can point out an error on my part that will make this all better.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637507/java-webdriver-element-not-visible-exception suggest to Click the Select first to open the dropdown.

The click will do two things

- Try to scroll to the element to get it in the current view port
- Open the dropdown, now the options are also visible

Answer (score 0):

Implement Explicit wait , Check below :

```
 WebElement Element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(xpathofyourdropdown));
```

Add above code just before your selenium find dropdown. It will wait till dropdown loads with values.

Comment: I would expect the waitForControl function todo something similar on the third line of the example.

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal - Might be , I am not familiar with that kind of wait so just suggested this to OP.

Comment: I think its a custom wrapper wait function written by the op. Maybe we should ask to show us that code too :)

Comment: Yep , You are right..:)

Comment: Yes, in the function waitforControl :
<code>
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, second))
                   .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.Xpath("xpaht")));
</code>

Comment: @scorpion - I see..Thanks for clarification..